# How the LabWindows CVI detects buffer overflow in C

Tags: c++, c

Yesterday,I find the CVI can detect buffer overflow when I run some simple code in C,which make me so confused.

```
void main(void)
{
int a[10];
int buf[10];    
int test[10];
int *p = &buf[10];
*p = 1;
while(1);
}
```

When I can run this program, the error is occurred.The message is "dereference of out-of-bounds pointer 1 bytes (1 elements) past end of array"(sorry for not permission to post the image)

I am so confused how to be implemented,as I know C/C++  don't have built-in array boundary. I also try in some other platform like VC++6.0 and Linux, and no one can detect the overflow. Thanks you.

Comment: It's possibly done with static analysis. It kept track of how big each array is, and when you indexed at 10 it realized that since the max index was 9, you were out of bounds.

Comment: I think this technology is very useful, why is not be used in other compiler,although I done understand what static analysis is

Comment: You mean don't? "I done understand" means you do.

Answer (score -1):

I've not used LabWindows/CVI, but from your brief discussion about it, I'm guessing it detected this out-of-bounds dereference at runtime, not at compile-time.  Static code analysis (correctness checks that can be performed at compile-time without running the software) are limited in the types of errors they can catch.  In your simple example, a compiler could conceivably catch this error, but it cannot catch errors like this in the general case because tracing the dataflow for all combinations of inputs that could go into a large program would be an intractable problem even for the most powerful supercomputers, even if left to chew on the problem for eons.

The only way this sort of problem can be caught in the general case is by dynamic program analysis:  By automatically instrumenting the code itself with runtime boundary checks, and/or by executing code through a simulator which tracks the boundaries of all memory allocations and verifies all accesses against those boundaries.  An example implementation of the former strategy is the Ada programming language, where mission-critical safety is considered far more important than performance.  But in the case of Ada, the language is designed to permit such checks.  An implementation of the C or C++ languages could probably do similar things, but the existence of raw pointers in the language would make that more difficult and perhaps prohibitively more runtime-expensive.

In C and C++, if you want this kind of runtime bounds-checking (only for testing), you might look into Valgrind.  I know of no other tool that's more thorough in catching out-of-bounds accesses.  But be prepared for your program to run really slowly.  Perhaps LabWindows/CVI is similar to Valgrind?

In any case, you need to be aware that regardless of what verification tool you use, the only way to catch buggy code with runtime bounds-checking is if you supply input to the program which evokes the out-of-bound behavior.  The absence of bounds-check failures from any verification tool is not a definitive indicator that your program has no such bugs.

Comment: @user2712796 - You're welcome.  If you found my answer useful, please select it (click on the check-mark) to "pay" me for my time (_you_ don't pay anything... it's free, but I would appreciate the points).  If you found it exceptionally useful, please also upvote it.  (Though you may not be able to upvote until you get higher rep points yourself.)

Comment: It is truly difficult to imagine why someone would feel the need to downvote my answer. The question is about "how can LabWindows/CVI detect an out-of-bounds access", and though I have no experience with LabWindows/CVI itself, I do have experience with other tools which can detect out-of-bounds array accesses. Though LabWinodws/CVI may detect it in a different manner, my answer certainly describes "how" a program might be able to do that. And there were no other answers, let alone answers that were better than mine. I'm sorry that someone felt the need to punish me for trying my best to help.